# Pandas split column of (unequal length) list into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

A slight variant to this question: [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Given a dataframe:

```
col1
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

How can I convert this into a dataframe with columns equal to the maximum length?

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0    1    2 
0    1 
0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0    1    2    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pandas` `DataFrame` re-create you `df`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.col1.values.tolist())
```