# split entries dictionary entries for dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
                item1                     item2                        item3
777    {'value1':x, 'value2':a}    {'value1':y, 'value2':a}    {'value1':z, 'value2':c}
778    {'value1':x, 'value2':b}    {'value1':z, 'value2':c}    { }
779    {'value1':y, 'value2':a}    {'value1':z, 'value2':d}    {'value1':w, 'value2':b}
...
```

How can form the following dataframe,

```
          item1        value2      item2        value2       item3  value2

 777       x              a          y             a           z      c     
 778       x              b          z             c         none       none
 779       y              a          z             d           w      b
```

The main dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item1':[{'value1':'x', 'value2':'a'}, {'value1':'x', 'value2':'b'}, {'value1':'y', 'value2':'a'}], 'item2':[{'value1':'y', 'value2':'a'}, {'value1':'z', 'value2':'c'}, {'value1':'z', 'value2':'d'}], 'item3':[{'value1':'z', 'value2':'c'}, {'value1':'none', 'value2':'none'}, {'value1':'w', 'value2':'b'}]})
```

So,  I try with `.apply(pd.Series)`, but I don't see how can do this. Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column of (unequal length) list into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228901/pandas-split-column-of-unequal-length-list-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve *exacly* your output via a simple dict comprehension and `str.get()`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({ col    : df[col].str.get('value1'), 
                         'value2': df[col].str.get('value2')}) \
                for col in df.columns],
           axis=1)
```

---

```
    item1 value2 item2 value2 item3 value2
777     x      a     y      a     z      c
778     x      b     z      c  None   None
779     y      a     z      d     w      b
```

---

Notice that it is definitely not recommended to have columns with duplicate names. You can always change `'value2'` to `f'{col}-value2'` as the key in your dict comprehension to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing new dataframe from stacking of columns of dicts:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack().tolist(), index=df.stack().index).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)

Out[480]:
    value1 value2 value1 value2 value1 value2
     item1  item1  item2  item2  item3  item3
777      x      a      y      a      z      c
778      x      b      z      c   none   none
779      y      a      z      d      w      b
```